# Vue - How can I list the array in the first object of the array with Vuex using mapState

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuex

I want to list the array named names of the first object in players using mapState with Vuex. In the current code, the objects in the players are listed according to their titles, but I want to filter them only according to the names in the first object on that page. On second page I want to list them according to the names that I will add to the second object. I hope I was able to explain my problem. How can I do this in the filter? Or what if there is a better way to do this?

Players.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="Players">
    <CostumText class="Players-title" tag="h1">Kulüpler</CostumText>
    <div class="Players-search">
      <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Kulüp ara.." />
      <label>Futbolcu ara:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="Players-inner">
      <router-link
        :to="players.pathName"
        class="Players-inner-wrapper"
        v-for="players in filteredList"
        v-bind:key="players.id"
      >
        <div class="Players-inner-cards">
          <Clubs class="Players-inner-cards-svg" v-bind:name="players.id" />
          <CostumText tag="strong" lang="tr" class="Players-inner-cards-text">
            {{ players.title }}
          </CostumText>
        </div>
      </router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import CostumText from '@/components/CostumText'
import Clubs from '@/components/Clubs.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Players',
  components: {
    CostumText,
    Clubs
  },
  data() {
    return {
      search: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['players']),
    filteredList() {
      return this.players.filter((player) =>
        player.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      )
    }
  },
  modules: {}
}
</script>
```

store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    players: [
      {
        id: 1,
        names: ['kerem', 'sirin', 'ali', 'ayse', 'ahmet'],
        title: 'Ali',
        pathName: 'ali'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Ayse',
        pathName: 'ayse'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Ahmet',
        pathName: 'ahmet'
      }
    ]
  },
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the filteredList to be

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['players']),
    filteredList() {
      const filteredPlayers = this.players.filter(player => {
        let flag = false;
        if(player.names) {
         player.names.forEach(name => {
          if(name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) flag = true;
         });
        }
       return flag;
    });
    return filteredPlayers;
  },
```

Here is how you display names

```
<div class="Players-inner-cards">
          <Clubs class="Players-inner-cards-svg" v-bind:name="players.id" />
          <CostumText tag="strong" lang="tr" class="Players-inner-cards-text">
            {{ players.names.valueOf() }}
          </CostumText>
        </div>
```

Comment: It says on console: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" :(

Comment: The code is working now thank you so much for that but on template in CostumText component I call names with player.title and so in the screen it shows just one component that named ''Ali'' (first objects title). How can I change it to names?

Comment: Btw, if your problem is solved, pls do accept the answer...thankyou :)

Comment: With this, names array is showing in one component. I want just one name in one component and want to show all names in another components with v-for (in router-link).